# Javascript document.getElementById("name") returning

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, getelementbyid

I've searched for the answer to my question and haven't been able to find anything that really hits it, as far as I saw.

I have two chunks of Javascript here that I am using to create a simple 2d game in a web browser.

```
var myGamePiece;

var game = {

    canvas : document.getElementById("game-screen"),

    start : function(){
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    }
}

function startGame(){
    game.start();
}
```

And this one:

```
var myGamePiece;

var game = {

    start : function(){

        this.canvas = document.getElementById("game-screen");
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");

    }
}

function startGame(){
    game.start();
}
```

The first code snippet does not work. The `canvas` is NULL when I try to get the context. I'm wondering why? I realize why it works in the second one, well, I assume I do. It's beeing run in a function. Is the `canvas` attribute in the first one not being 'run' like it is in the second code snippet?

Comments and tips appreciated! :D

Comment: You probably have the first script before the `game-screen` element in the HTML, so the element doesn't exist yet when the code runs. Put it at the bottom of the HTML and it will work.

Comment: True. I have it in the <head> so should I just link it in with <script src="creative.js"></script> later on in the html file? Where exactly should I put it then?

Comment: Either put it at the end of the body, or put your code in the `window.onload` function so it runs after the document is loaded. Aren't these solutions explained in the duplicate question I linked to?

Comment: Well, I apologize for the duplicate question. I didn't know how to formulate the problem I was having into words. Thanks for the link, I'll look at that now. Cheers.

Comment: Don't worry about it. Questions like this come up multiple times every day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first code calls `document.getElementById("game-screen")` immediately in the `var game` declaration.

That's probably running before the element exists.

Comment: Ah, well that would make sense.